# Count new and returning items by year

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, self-join

Following up on the question "[Select new or returning items for a specified year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853891/select-new-or-returning-items-for-a-specified-year)", I would now like to create statistics on how many items per year are new or returning. Here's my example table:

```
+---------------------+----------+
| date                | item     |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2008-11-30 11:15:59 | Plums    |
| 2012-11-08 19:42:37 | Lemons   |
| 2013-01-30 18:58:07 | Apples   |
| 2013-02-12 13:44:45 | Pears    |
| 2014-06-08 11:46:48 | Apples   |
| 2014-09-01 20:28:03 | Oranges  |
+---------------------+----------+
```

I'm looking for a query which will return the amount of items that have not appeared in **previous** years, and the amount of items that have already appeared in previous years.

The result should look something along the lines of this:

```
Year   New Items   Returning Items
2008   1           0
2012   1           0
2013   2           0
2014   1           1
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using the queries you are linking to, I came up with the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d915/57/0)):

```
SELECT m1.UniqYear,  
  CASE WHEN m2.NewItems IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE m2.NewItems END AS NewItems,
  CASE WHEN m3.ReturningItems IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE m3.ReturningItems END AS ReturningItems
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(s.date) AS UniqYear 
  FROM MyTable s
) m1 LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT YEAR(s1.date) AS Year, COUNT(*) AS NewItems
  FROM MyTable s1
    LEFT JOIN MyTable s2 ON s1.item = s2.item AND YEAR(s2.date) < YEAR(s1.date)
  WHERE s2.date IS NULL
  GROUP BY YEAR(s1.date)
) m2 ON m1.UniqYear = m2.Year
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT YEAR(s3.date) AS Year, COUNT(*) AS ReturningItems
  FROM MyTable s3
    INNER JOIN MyTable s4 ON s3.item = s4.item
  WHERE YEAR(s4.date) < YEAR(s3.date)
  GROUP BY YEAR(s3.date)
) m3 ON m1.UniqYear = m3.Year
ORDER BY m1.UniqYear;
```

I am using the **CASE** statements to return `0` instead off `null`.  The first sub query (`m1`) is used to get the distinct years.  The second sub query (`m2`) is used to get the **New Items** count.  The third sub query (`m3`) is used to get the **Returning Items** count. Notice I had to add a group by statement to get the count per year.  I had to `LEFT JOIN`ed `m2` and `m3` to `m1` because you are not always going to have a **NewItems** count or a **Returning Items** for every year.

Comment: Almost perfect! Still two minor things missing for me: 
1) The results are not properly ordered by year when I run the query on my table. I've tried adding an `ORDER BY year(s.timestamp) ASC` but it's not working yet. I'm not quite sure where to put the ORDER BY, or whether to use s.date, s1.date etc...
2) For the purposes of statistics, I am looking to group items. I was able to achieve the correct result by replacing `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT s#.item)`

Comment: **@rayne**, to order by the year add `ORDER BY m1.UniqYear` to the end of the query.  I have updated my answer showing you how.